# Multistep form vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inject, emit, multi-step

**I'm trying to reform a multistep form, but my first step and second step are visualised both at the same time now. Even though my app data is having an activePhase data stored. It seem like I should be using as a method some emit logic? Or as I'm usin Provide/Inject I should use Reactivity as here - https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity   ?

See the link please - https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-jasper-teh1im?file=/src/components/Step2.vue**

```js
<template v-if="activePhase == 2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <h1>Step 1</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Payment Amount</label
        ><input
          name="paymentAmount"
          v-model="paymentAmount"
          placeholder="Your payment amount"
          class="form-control"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Account Number</label
        ><input
          name="accountNumber"
          v-model="accountNumber"
          placeholder="Your account number"
          class="form-control"
        />
      </div>
      <button type="button" @click.prevent="goToStep(3)" class="btn">
        Continue
      </button>
    </div>
    <Button />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Button from "./Button.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Button,
  },
  inject: ["activePhase", "paymentAmount", "accountNumber"],
  methods: {
    goToStep(step) {
      this.activePhase = step;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) for this use case.

So that your form accept 1 child, which will change overtime.

```html
<template>
  <Form>
    <component :is="currentStep" />
  </Form>
</template>

<script>
import Step1 from './Step1.vue'
import Step2 from './Step2.vue'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      steps: [Step1, Step2],
      stepIndex: 0,
    }
  },
  methods {
    nextStep() {
      this.stepIndex++
    }
  },
  computed {
    currentStep() {
      return this.steps[this.stepIndex]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I replaced the code, but now getting the Maximum call stack size exceeded Error. As well in IDE. What should I do ? https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-jasper-teh1im?file=/src/components/Form.vue

Comment: Your `Form` component calls himself, hence the recursive calls and max call stack exceeded. Just remove the `<Form>` and only keep the `<component :is />`

Comment: But what i'd I'd like to keep the structure with a nested Form component with two child components ?

Comment: What do you mean a nested Form? You could, but just be careful it's not going into an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what if I'd like to have the data not inside the Form component but inside the app.vue file. How would it look like ?